# SQL hot to count alias entries bigger 1

Tags: mysql, sql, pgadmin

I want to know only the totals which are bigger than 1 therefore I wrote this query, but I don't know how to check if the total sum is bigger than 1.
The SQL-Code:

```
SELECT P.Customer, COUNT(*) as TOTAL
FROM Projects P
WHERE total > 1
GROUP BY P.Customer
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvjBx.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.Customer, COUNT(*) as TOTAL
FROM Projects P
GROUP BY P.Customer
HAVING SUM(total) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `WHERE` you can use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT P.Customer, COUNT(*)
FROM Projects P
GROUP BY P.Customer
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```